# rail-composer install issue using rails 4 and mongoid 4

Tags: ruby, git, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

Try to use the rail-composer to build an skeleton app by selecting 3 option which is to build my own app.  Pick Mongoid as default DB, Thin as webserver for both dev and prod. Chose to have a Starter app of home page, user, admin dashboards.

While running the script the following error popped up and seems like its breaking when trying to update the mongoid gem.

Could not find gem 'mongoid (~> 4) ruby' in
git://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git (at master).
Source contains 'mongoid' at: 4.0.0.alpha1
composer  Updating gem paths.

Then the script doesn't finish.  Anyone know what causes this problem?

Comment: Hi Joe. Did you find a solution to this issue? I have the same.

Comment: See my comment below.  I exchanged brief email w/ author of the rail-composer and he mentioned that part of the code may not work as expected. So I suspect its a bug.  I am building my app from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

Replace:

```
 gem 'mongoid', '~> 4', :github=>"mongoid/mongoid"
```

with:

```
 gem 'mongoid', :github=>"mongoid/mongoid"
```

Comment: But my problem was in the Rail Composer. If I were to install it independently I tried the gem 'mongoid', :github=>'mongoid/mongoid' works.  Apparently the options I selected in the rail composer for rail 4 + mongoid isn't fully written and author mentioned about taking that options off from the install process.

Comment: But it fails by finishing the setup, but printing an error message about bundle install being unable to finish, right?